# Erlang message processing transaction

Tags: erlang

When is the "transaction" of a process trying to fetch a message from its message queue considered to be committed or rolled back? In other words, at what point of execution is the message removed permanently from the message queue?

Comment: There's a fairly nice write up on the mechanism underlying receive here: http://ndpar.blogspot.co.za/2010/11/erlang-explained-selective-receive.html

Answer (score 3):

When it is read by a receive call.

If a message is in a message queue and read by the process calling receive then it's just memory manipulation, and no other process can contend for the data so there's no transactional nature to it as such; there's no need for locking or rolling back, etc, but because it's just memory manipulation it doesn't matter.

The language you use makes me worry you think there are more guarantees than there are. It's important to remember that at the fundamental message send and receive level (without any extra layer on top that OTP might provide or you might write yourself) you are sending messages without any guarantee they will be delivered, or that the process you are sending to even exists.

Comment: So in other words, there is no "rollback" and when a receive is matched then the message is removed permanently from the mailbox.

Comment: In essence, message, when matched, goes from the queue to your variable, there's no case for any kind of rollback.

Comment: "no other process can contend for the data so there's no transactional nature to it as such" this is not true, think about an outside observer that can check the mailbox status or check the number of messages and make a decision based on that. Maybe the process itself is in a suspended state in the middle of a receive, in that case it does make a difference when the message is actually removed from the mailbox.

Comment: No since no one else can remove the message from the mailbox except the receiver.  I think you have the wrong impression of what Erlangs process mailboxes are.  They are a very lightweight construct to build more complicated things out of and nota tiny Rabbit MQ like message bus

Comment: @GaborKulcsar Peer is right, and any 'observation' of the message queue by another process can never be transactional because any observation is a snap shot in time, it must be consistent, but the foreign process can never take an atomic isolated decision based on the observation because it will always be a bit like looking at the light from Alpha Centauri - that was how it looked once, a long time ago.

Comment: @Peer: this is what I was thinking about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Dirty_reads
 - just because there is only one writer there can be mulitple concurrent readers.

Comment: @Michael: "but because it's just memory manipulation it doesn't matter." Are you familiar with STM? Eg. http://clojure.org/refs#Refs%20and%20Transactions

Comment: You CAN have transactions in memory yes, but we don't want transactions unless it is necessary, and we don't want locks when it isn't necessary. Those things harm performance. There is no requirement for a transaction in this case within the Erlang paradigm. Clojure is incomparable, it features "shared use of mutable storage", where as Erlang generally features neither shared or mutable storage (the obvious exception being ETS, but that has nothing to do with messages or message queues).